# Using a content provider to query data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver, android-loader

*What is the best way to use the `ContentProvider` to query data from my database?*

I was told to never perform database functions on the `UI Thread`.

*Is there a special loader to use when I want to perform `getContentResolver.query(...)`?*

Comment: Yes, it's called a CursorLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from 'special loader' that you're using a Loader?  From what I gather, the Loader construct was written with ContentProvider in mind (sort of).  I gather that from talking with Google engineers.

Loaders in general are designed to load data in a background thread, so if you use them as directed, you'll be good.

Read about CursorLoader, which is what you want

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

To add my own 2 cents, if you're not sharing data outside of your app, ContentProvider is just extra work and code, but saying that makes ContentProvider fans upset, so feel free to ignore me.

Comment: I may want to share the data outside of the app. I just found out about AsyncQueryHandler. I will look into this.

Comment: IMO, a ContentProvider provides a great framework for abstracting data access. Since you usually have to design such an abstraction anyway, using the ContentProvider framework is a decent way to go.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Its a long discussion. Short answer, you need to write a surrogate query language, largely based on URLs. Complex or dynamic queries are extremely difficult and clunky.  You're also still writing your abstractions on the other side of your URL barrier. Its just extra work. However, I have failed to convince many, so I don't try very hard.  I gave a talk about this at Droidcon Berlin. I'd say responses were 50/50.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Here! http://de.droidcon.com/2014/session/lift-your-back Wish I had the video, though...

Comment: @KevinGalligan You make some good points. My experience with writing a ContentProvider is quite basic.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Don't assume I'm right, though.  Have had semi-heated discussions about this with Google engineers, if that means anything. The real point of my talk is use the right tool, and think about what others are telling you ;)